# which data structure should I use for trading system?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have finished my studying of a basic trading system structure and going to build one now. I am going to put a table of historical data (having columns of day high, day low...etcs of days of many years) into an array or other kind of data structure, then use the date to do analysis, and some analysis would need to put the result into another array (or another data structure).

So basically it would be few "tables" with each having around 6 columns and around 2000-5000 rows. I would do calculations within these tables and then store the result to another similar size table.

Array is good enough? Or I should choose another data structure like linked list?

Comment: arrays good enough while has some limitation over lists, but I think they are more faster, the data-structure isn't just the issue, you need to program your application to run and process data ASAP, maybe you need process data parallel, or etc.

Comment: I see, so you mean array has very good speed right? My first version would be just single thread first, if later I really need higher speed, then I make it muti threading. For data structure, even after some formal study before, I am still confused about what I should choose.

Comment: as I said, arrays are more faster, but have some limitations (size, swapping, sort, ...), it depends on what do you want to do exactly with this set of info! and sometimes a good data-structure gets satisfied by a bad algorithm, beware of sequential processes

Comment: When i create an 2d array for storing result, i may not know the size.

Comment: what lang are you going to use? hope it's be java

Comment: Yes java. Going to use mysql to store historical data. I will develop and run in windows 7 64bits in my  existing desktop first, if later if this is profitable enough then use part of the profit to buy a much faster desktop and run with ubuntu 64 and move java and mysql to it.

Comment: good, so in java 2D array, in each index, this is possible to have different length arrays, for example int[10][], the index [0] would have 19 data, while index [1] would have 190, but you should know about how much arrays do you need

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your requirements.

If you are just doing simple analysis on relatively small amounts of data (sounds like this is the case?) then there's no need to be too fancy. Probably a simple `ArrayList` of rows would work well. Keep it simple.

If performance is a concern then you need to understand the usage pattern a lot more. For example, if you are doing a lot of read-only lookups then you may want to create indexes into the data (e.g. using HashMaps). But that's getting quite advanced.

So for now, I suggest sticking with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: hmmm mainly because ArrayLists have more useful/higher level functionality - you can add elements, you can access sublists etc. arrays are a lower level construct. Your default choice should usually be an ArrayList, unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: I just check it out, 2d arraylist requires declare arraylist in arraylist while 2d array is much more simple.

Comment: At a syntax level arrays might be simpler. at a conceptual level it's effectively the same thing. In higher order code, ArrayLists will be more flexible. Your call.

Comment: Mine will be mainly 2d, not easy to keep using arrylist in arrylist